# Linear Control Lock?

Tags: thrust, flight-control

Assume a spacecraft with a less-than-perfect maneuvering thruster configuration such that in a particular attitude while attempting to dock, the thrusters will not allow translation along a particular axis.  As a result, the spacecraft has to roll and translate in another direction to compensate.

It's like a linear analogue to gimbal lock.  Is there a term for this situation?

Comment: PDSS Poorly Designed Spacecraft Syndrome?

Comment: SOL (closest star)

Comment: In robotics I think I would use "non-holonomic". (It means a system, like a vehicle, that is constrained in certain axes in such a way that it can only get into certain positions with extra manoeuvring. Just like a car that cannot "slide" sideways into a parking space.) I haven't heard the term used in aerospace though it should be applicable...